# Spring MVC Multipart : Is name parameter in the Content-Disposition is mandatory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload the files to the api with content-disposition

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=image.jpg;
```

Api looks like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/channels/{channelId}/song", method = POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity create(@PathVariable UUID channelId, MultipartRequest multipartRequest)
```

I don't get image.jpg in the multipartRequest.

Note : I dont want to use @RequestParam or @RequestPart as filename is not fix.

If I do

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=image.jpg; filename=image.jpg;
```

it works.

According to Content-Disposition spec, name doesn't seems to be mandatory but somehow Spring MVC is not working.

Comment: You can use for both.

Comment: My mistake. Which multipart resolver do you use? Maybe that makes a difference. I recommend to use `List<MultipartFile>` instead of `MultipartRequest`.